# How to not invalidate observer when binding is disposed in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, binding, dispose, rx-swift

I'm quite new in RxSwift world and apparently I'm not using it correctly... I have a button that I would like to connect to an observer like this

```
button.rx.tap.bind(to: viewModel.someObserver).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

where `someObserver` in viewModel is initialized as follows:

```
let publishSubject = PublishSubject<Void>()
someObserver = publishSubject.asObserver()
someObservable = publishSubject.asObservable()
```

However, when `Disposable` created with binding is disposed, `PublishSubject` which is used both as `Observer` and `Observable` gets invalidated and all new subscriptions are immediately disposed.

I would like to use my `PublishSubject` for a longer time and be able to subscribe to it after the binding is disposed. How to achieve that?

Comment: Who's the owner of `disposeBag` which stores the result of button.rx.tap.bind? as long as it's the property of a viewControllers/view which holds the button, it shouldn't dispose until viewController/view is not deinited. Do you mean you need to keep subscription for a longer period of time than the lifetime of your UI component?

Comment: @Nimble exactly yes, the button is inside the UITableViewCell that owns `disposeBag` and `someObserver` is owned by view model of entire UIViewController holding UITableView. When I reload table view, the binding of current cell is disposed and new is created.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [`PublishRelay`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/b3e888b4972d9bc76495dd74d30a8c7fad4b9395/RxRelay/PublishRelay.swift), which can't terminate with an error or completed event.

Binding the taps to a `PublishRelay` will simply ignore the completed event ([source](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/b3e888b4972d9bc76495dd74d30a8c7fad4b9395/RxRelay/Observable%2BBind.swift#L52-L53)) once the subscription is disposed, e.g. when the button is deallocated. This will allow you to subscribe to the `PublishRelay` at a later point